# Why no data returns when I use unnest in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
SELECT 
date,
count(visitNumber) as visits,
product.v2ProductName,
sum(productRevenue) as Revenue,
product.v2ProductCategory,
concat(trafficSource.source,'/', trafficSource.medium) as source_medium, 
promo.promoName
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170*` t,
UNNEST(t.hits) as hits ,UNNEST(hits.product) as product, UNNEST(hits.promotion) as promo

WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '601' AND '605'
Group by date, product.v2ProductName,product.v2ProductCategory ,promo.promoName, source_medium
ORDER BY date ASC
```

I was using JOIN before but my supervisor told me to do it without JOINS. So I did but now it returns no data at all. What's wrong here in this syntax?

Comment: As I commented in your previous question, there is no case where `hits.promotion` and `hits.product` has values at the same time which makes the comma or inner join of 2 arrays return nothing.

Comment: the query looks very strange, it would be better to have sample data as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using LEFT JOIN with UNNEST;

```
SELECT 
date,
count(visitNumber) as visits,
product.v2ProductName,
sum(productRevenue) as Revenue,
product.v2ProductCategory,
concat(trafficSource.source,'/', trafficSource.medium) as source_medium, 
promo.promoName
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170*` t 
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(t.hits) as hits LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits.product) as product LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits.promotion) as promo
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '601' AND '605'
Group by 1, product.v2ProductName,product.v2ProductCategory ,promo.promoName, source_medium
ORDER BY date ASC;
```